# VBA function for pulling multiple values from single cell and index/matching them to values

Tags: vba, indexing, split, match, explode

I'm having trouble with a user defined function to explode a single cell string into multiple values, then match each of those values in an index/match fashion, returning a single cell with a string for the matched values separated by commas.

Example:

```
Roles             Names           Role      Name
role1/role2       name1,name2     role1     name1
role1             name1           role2     name2
role2/role3       name2,name3     role3     name3
role1/role4       name1,name4     role4     name4
role3/role5       name3,name5     role5     name5
```

I want to get a function that generates the "names" column from the Roles, Role, and Name columns.

Here's my VBA code so far:

```
Public Function RoleToName(role, roles_rng, names_rng) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim s As Variant

    For Each s In Split(role, "/")
        ???
    Next s
End Function
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to accomplish. Could you show the results you'd like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Function RoleToName(role, roles_rng, names_rng) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim s As Variant, m, sep As String

    For Each s In Split(role, "/")
        'Trim each value in case of extra spaces...
        m = Application.Match(Trim(s), roles_rng, 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            result = result & sep & names_rng.Cells(m).Value
        Else
            result = result & sep & "??" '<< role not found...
        End If
        sep = ","
    Next s
    RoleToName = result
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Try it as,

```
Function udf_CollateNames(roles As String, tbl As Range, _
                          Optional roleSplit As String = "/", _
                          Optional delim As String = ",")
    Dim v As Long, vVALs As Variant

    vVALs = Split(roles, roleSplit)

    For v = LBound(vVALs) To UBound(vVALs)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Trim(vVALs(v)), tbl.Columns(1), 0)) Then _
            udf_CollateNames = udf_CollateNames & delim & Application.VLookup(Trim(vVALs(v)), tbl, 2, False)
    Next v

    udf_CollateNames = Mid(udf_CollateNames, Len(delim) + 1)
End Function
```

[image]